# Can I use Pivot Tables/Slicers to generate a table list with details from a large excel sheet?

Tags: excel

I was given an excel list from my boss to set us a Dashboard using Pivot Tables, Pivot Charts and Slicers. This part was easy and no problem with it.

What I would like to do is when an option is selected on the Slicers a list on the same page is automatically generated with details from the main excel sheet.

Example: Salesperson A has 5 deals, this is selected on the Slicers, the Salesperson deals would be automatically generated below.

Name_____Client______Revenue______etc

1. 
2. 
3. 
4. 
5. Any ideas on how this can be done?

General Ideas will be fine I can look it up myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you include those fields in the pivot table when you setup the slicers then all of that information should show up.

Comment: Thanks you for Answering. I see where you are coming from after looking at a few older excel videos on pivot tables. When a new option is added to the Row Label, the details are added to the next Column, A, B, C, etc. only my pivot table has all the Row Labels in Column A. I am using excel version 2016, is there a way to change this?

Comment: Thanks for your help, you put me on the right path, all I needed to do was change the Report Layout to Tabular Form and then I could add as many Row Labels as I like.